# How to resize moveit Setup Assistant?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My movie setup assistant's button is almost disappeared.

[image: image description]

How to resize this window?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65718/how-to-resize-moveit-setup-assistant?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2013-06-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-08-05**:
any solution yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[A patch to make the window smaller](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_setup_assistant/pull/105) is just accepted. It should become available with a next "apt gettable" version of `moveit_setup_assistant`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1